# Generic type class content need to be displayed

Tags: java, json, parsing, generics, types

I have certain entity classes which I generated from json file. I want to check my entity classes are correct so I have a parseDescriptor method and am reading the value ttoa generic class type. Can some one please tell how can I display the content from generic class object(ret in my case)?

```
public <T> T parseDescriptor(String json, Class<T> c) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.getDeserializationConfig().disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            mapper.getDeserializationConfig().enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
            T ret = mapper.readValue(json, c);
            if (!(ret instanceof ReportDescriptor)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified class of type "+c.getCanonicalName()+" does not extend ReportDescriptor");
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (JsonParseException jpe) {
:
:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display the content"?

Comment: Note that you wouldn't need the instanceof check if you bounded `<T extends ReportDescriptor>`.

Comment: @Andy Turner am trying to get the json content from my java pojo to check my entity classes are correct. Am actually confused what is the data from mapper.readValue(json, c); Thank you

Comment: If ret is an instance of ReportDescriptor, you can cast your object to that class. You can then use the functions of that class to do with it what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If ret is an instance of ReportDescriptor, you can cast your object to that class. You can then use the functions of that class to do with it what you want.

```
//Cast the object
ReportDescriptor reportDescriptor = (ReportDescriptor) ret;
//For example, call the toString() function of that class
reportDescriptor.toString();
```